# Check if variable contains an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a method in Java that reverses an array or matrix. The method's code as it is now looks like this:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T[] reverse(T[] array) {
    T[] ret = Array.newInstance(array.getClass().getComponentType(), array.length);
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].getClass().getComponentType() != null) {
            ret[array.length - 1 - i] = (T) reverse((T[]) array[i]); // the exception (see below) occurs here
        } else {
            ret[array.length - 1 - i] = array[i];
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

When I tried to run this method with a 2-dimensional `String` matrix, it worked out well. Now I tried to use an 2-dimensional `int` matrix instead and I get the following exception:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

<del>How come this code works with `String` arrays, but not with `int` arrays? How can I fix the code to work with `int` arrays as well?</del>

---

@EDIT I just noticed that I asked this question wrong. *facepalms* What I originally wanted to know is: how do I check if `array[i]` is an array or not?

Comment: because int is not an Object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Integer` instead. `int` is a *primitive type* where `String` is an *object type*.

See [Restrictions on Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html):

> Cannot Instantiate Generic Types with Primitive Types

See also the example they provide:

Quote >

```
class Pair<K, V> {

    private K key;
    private V value;

    public Pair(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    // ...
}
```

When creating a `Pair` object, you cannot substitute a primitive type for the type parameter `K` or `V`:

```
Pair<int, char> p = new Pair<>(8, 'a');  // compile-time error
```

<

Comment: I'm sorry, I asked this question wrong. Your answer is - of course - correct concerning my problems with String[] and int[], but I originally wanted to know how I can check if a variable is an array or not.

Comment: @flashdrive2049 `if(someObj.getClass().isArray())`? Or `if(someObj instanceof Object[])`